# Adding "Activate the extension" shortcut to Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I am developing a Chrome Extension for personal use and want to add a shortcut to it to activate to `popup.html` page (i.e. when I press the shortcut the `popup.html` page will show up).

For some extension I can easily do this by going to `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` page and assigning a shortcut against "Activate the extension" field.

But my extension is not listed there.

Do I need to add anything to the `manifest.json` file for my extension to appear in `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` page?

Comment: You need to define browser_action (MV2) or action (MV3) in manifest.json.

Comment: I agree with wOxxOm's comment. For more information, you can also refer to [this blog](https://blog.shahednasser.com/how-to-add-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-chrome-extension/): *Action commands map the shortcuts to your extension's action (if MV3) or browser action or page action (if MV2).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Yu Zhou for sharing [this link](https://blog.shahednasser.com/how-to-add-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-chrome-extension/) in his comment. It helped me to make the "Activate the extension" thing to work.

To make the extension available in `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` you need to add the following in `manifest.json` -

```
"commands": {
    "_execute_action": {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
        }
    }
},
```

But doing only this doesn't make the shortcut assigned to actually work. For that you need to add a `background.js` page -

```
// in manifext.json
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
}
```

```
// in background.js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    //TODO toggle dark mode in the tab
});
```

I am still unclear on how all these are making the `popus.html` to activate but it is working now.

P.S. this is for **manifest version 3**

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Just to note that I don't think the `service_worker` part is necessary to just get your extension dialog to show. I was a bit confused by this too, there doesn't seem to be much information online about chrome extensions.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm migrating from MV2->MV3 and still not able to get the hotkey to invoke the extension to work.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Best Answer' did not work for me, after a confusing 20 minutes I found out that all you need in your MV3 file is this:

```
"commands": {
  "_execute_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
        "mac": "Shift+MacCtrl+G"
      },
    "description" : "Start the extension"
    }
}
```

The catch was that I needed to fully `Remove` my extension and then `Load unpacked` for mine to work.

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't apply to you if you're only developing something for your own personal use, but for others who may land on this answer, please note that if you assign a default, that means that users can never ***unset*** that shortcut. This is likely an [issue with Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275357).